# Retrieving non-header context from Apollo Server

Tags: javascript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I keep seeing examples about setting context on Apollo Client like this :

```js
new ApolloClient({
    uri: '...',
    request(operation) {
      const currentUser = readStore<CurrentUser>("currentUser");
      currentUser &&
        operation.setContext({
          headers: { authorization: currentUser.token },
          other: "things"
        });
    }
  });
}
```

With things that go to the request headers, and "other" things. Yet after more than 2h of research, I couldn't find one example of that other context data being retrieved on the other end, on Apollo Server.

It seems like all the examples are about authorization tokens, but how to I retrieve the rest, say using `apollo-server-express` ?

Here is what I have so far :

```js
const apollo = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context({ req }): Context {
    const currentUser =
      (req.headers.authorization &&
        (jwt.verify(
          req.headers.authorization,
          process.env.JWTSIGN
        ) as Context["currentUser"])) ||
      null;

    // Ok for req.headers.authorization, how to I get "other: things" ?

    return {
      ip: req.ip,
      currentUser
    };
  }
});
```

The `context` function here only gets a req and a res object from Express. After some logs, it doesn't seem to contain the data I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason it appears headers are shared in the example you shared is because `ApolloClient` uses the `headers` value inside its context to populate the [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) it sends when making a request. Those headers are then parsed by `express` and made available on the `req` object. The context used by `ApolloClient` is strictly client-side. The context used by `ApolloServer` is strictly server-side. You can't use `ApolloClient`'s context to pass arbitrary values to your server -- you should utilize headers or arguments inside your GraphQL query for that.